# pushbuttonfield with double byte character

Tags: java, itext

Searched around on Google as well as stackoverflow but didn't see this come up anywhere. I need a pushbuttonfield with double byte characters as the text. Does anybody know if this is possible?

Currently if I set the button text as any double byte text, the text won't show up. It shows up fine if it's just in the body of the PDF.

Edit#1: Double byte character set (DBCS) like Japanese, Russian, Dutch, etc.

Edit#2:

```
PushbuttonField myButton = new PushbuttonField(writer, rect, "myJapaneseButton"); 
myButton.setText("japanese text here");
```

Comment: What do you mean by double byte? Are you referring to wide character strings?

Comment: Ideally, please give a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. It's very unclear at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the [CreateJapaneseButton](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/CreateJapaneseButton) example. It creates a PDF with a button that looks like this:

[image]

Your code snippet is very short, but you probably have all the code you need, except the line that sets the font:

```
public static final String JAPANESE = "\u3042\u304d\u3089";
public static final String FONT = "resources/fonts/FreeSans.ttf";

public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    PushbuttonField button = new PushbuttonField(writer, new Rectangle(36, 780, 144, 806), "japanese");
    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    button.setFont(bf);
    button.setText(JAPANESE);
    writer.addAnnotation(button.getField());
    document.close();
}
```

If you don't set the font, the default font is used. The default font is the Standard Type 1 font Helvetica. This font doesn't know how to write Japanese. I used the font `freesans.ttf`. If you don't have that font, you can try `arialuni.ttf` or any other font that supports Japanese.